# AWS Connections & Virtual Interfacesについて

Tags: aws

AWSの初心者ですが、「絵で見てわかる　クラウドインフラとAPIの仕組み」を読んでいます。

その本では、AWS Direct Connectについて、こういう説明が取り上げられています。

> AWSでは、論理結線の単位としては、**バーチャルインターフェース**で構成され、APIのリソースとしては**コネクションID**を元に**接続**を確立します。コネクションIDは、プライベートAS番号、VLAN番号、双方のCIDR、プライベートゲートウェイIDなどの属性で構成され、***関連付けが行われます***。...

上述の文について、２つの質問がありますが、

1.　AWSのDocument[[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/getting_started.html#ConnectionRequest)と[API CreateConnectionのRequest Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/APIReference/API_CreateConnection.html)から見れば、接続を確立する場合、必要なのは**コネクションIDではなく**、帯域、コネクションの名前などの引数です。接続を確立した上で、コネクションIDが結果として返されるというわけです。「**コネクションID**を元に」という表現は正しいですか？

2.　「コネクションIDは、...などの属性で構成され、関連付けが行われます」と書いてありますが、**誰と誰の間で関連付けが行われますか**？

また、AWSのDocumentと比べ合わせて、CreatePrivateVirtualInterface, AllocatePrivateVirtualInterface, CreatePublicVirtualInterface, AllocatePublicVirtualInterfaceの４つのAPIについて、その本にも相違点があるようです。

その本では、

> CreatePrivateVirtualInterfaceのAPIを実行することで**コネクションIDが作成され**、AllocatePrivateVirtualInterfaceのAPIを実行することで**接続が完了します**。

一方、AWSのDocumentでは、
「Creates a private virtual interface. 」と「Provisions a private virtual interface to be owned by the specified AWS account.」とそれぞれ解釈されています。

同様に、

> AWSには、パブリックAS番号で**コネクションIDを作成する**APIが用意されており、CreatePublicVirtualInterfaceのAPIで実行して、パブリックAS番号などを使ってAllocatePrivateVirtualInterfaceで**接続を完了します**。

AWSでは「Creates a public virtual interface. 」と「Provisions a public virtual interface to be owned by the specified AWS account.」とそれぞれ解釈されています。

しかし、Create系のAPIは作成するのはコネクションIDではなく、virtual interfaceなのはずですが、Allocate系のAPIはvirtual interfaceの付与なのはずだと思います。

Answer (score 0):

このへんはやったことないので 間違ってるかもしれませんが、AWSドキュメントでは物理結線のことが書かれていて、書籍の方はソフトウェア的に行われる論理結線ということではないかと。

`createConnection` は カスタマゲートウェイ(オンプレのルータ)と、各地にある[DirectConnect Locations](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/directconnect/features/#AWS_Direct_Connect_Locations) との接続をリクエストするものですが、書籍の方は バーチャルインターフェースを使ってVPCと接続することを書いてるんだと思います。

Comment: 物理結線と論理結線とを混同してしまいました。ご指摘いただきましてありがとうございます。その本では、**コネクションID**が*バーチャルインターフェース*に変更されれば、分かりやすいと思いますが、take88さんもそう思っていますか。また、「コネクションIDは、...関連付けが行われます」とは、**カスタマゲートウェイとDirectConnect Locations**の間で関連が付けられるという意味ですか？

Comment: そもそもDirectConnectが分かりにくいんで 文章で表現するのは 大変だろうなとは思いますね。関連付けについては「コネクションIDと、バーチャルインターフェースが関連付られる」ことがすなわち、「論理結線が行われる」ということかなと理解してます。